# Resolve Firestore References

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Firestore has a `reference` type while defining fields of a document which allows us to add a reference to another document via its "Document path".

For example, I have the document `animals/3OYc0QTbGOTRkhXeiW0t`, with a field `name` having value `Zebra`. I reference it in the array `animals`, of document `zoo/xmo5wX0MLUEbfFJHvKq6`. I am basically storing a list of animals in a zoo, by referring the animals to the corresponding animal document in the `animals` collections.

Now if I query a specific document from the `zoo` collection, will references to the animals be automatically resolved? Will I the get the animal names in the query result? If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107572, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46674073, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48128827

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All document queries in Firestore are shallow, meaning that you only get one document in return for each document requested.

References in a document are not automatically fetched - you will have to make subsequent queries using the references in the document to get those other documents on your own.

Same thing with documents in subcollections - they require separate queries.

Comment: Is it possible to store the reference of the zoo with the animal? That way you could query all animals in a zoo (via the reference). This makes of course only sense when animals are unique (eg. Marty the Zebra)

Comment: You can't store whatever reference you want to any document within the same database.  To know what all you can do with references, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for

Comment: Thanks, @DougStevenson, Please would you know if firebase has added the ability to automatically resolve subqueries. Because the firestore wouldn't just make any sense again using it like that. I'll rather stick to SQL Join tables.